# CalculateField_management: Different results than in the field calculator

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, data-management

I`m using ArcMap 10.2.2 and Python 2.7.5

I´m tryig to calculate values with the CalculateField_management tool.

my script:

```
def mthree(mthre, mtwo):
    if mthre >= 1:
        return -3
    if mtwo >= 2:
        return -5
    else:
        return None

try:
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(FC, "EPK_Gesamt", mthree("countmd","countmz"),"PYTHON_9.3")
    print "done"
```

The Problem:
It writes in every row the same value (-3)
However if I do the same calculation within the Field Calculator it works great!
Has anyone an Idea what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your function with text values " " instead of field names ! !, therefore it returns true to the first condition.

just try this :

```
codeblock = """def mthree(mthre, mtwo):
        if mthre >= 1:
            return -3
        if mtwo >= 2:
            return -5
        else:
            return None """

expression="mthree(!countmd!,!countmz!)"

arcpy.CalculateField_management(FC, "EPK_Gesamt", expression,"PYTHON_9.3",codeblock)
```

Comment: I see the problem. But if I try using the exclamation marks, python gives me an "invalid syntax" error (standalone script). Is that somehow a path related problem? I`m working with data in .gdb format

Comment: sorry, I went a bit fast, I've edited the expression with the codeblock.